# Using PageView And Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one problem with `PageView` widget and `Provider`...

I have a model:

```dart
class RegistrationModel with ChangeNotifier {
  int _pageIndex;
  int _currentPage = 0;

  setCurrentPage(int value) {
    _currentPage = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And Register page when a user step by step inputs register information:

```dart
class RegistrationPagesView extends StatelessWidget {
  PageController pageController;

  RegistrationPagesView({this.pageController});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<RegistrationModel>(
        builder: (ctx, registrationModel, widget) {
          final pageView = PageView(
          onPageChanged: (value) {
            ctx.read<RegistrationModel>().setCurrentPage(value);
          },
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        pageSnapping: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          FirstStepRegisterPage(),
          NewsPageRegistr(),
          MagazinePageRegistr(),
          RightPageRegistr(),
        ],
      );
      if(registrationModel.currentPage != pageController.page.floor()) {
        pageController.jumpToPage(registrationModel.currentPage);
      }
        return pageView;
    });
  }
}
```

And when I run App this is the error thrown below:

```
Error: "PageController.page cannot be accessed before a PageView is built with it.
'package: flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart': 
Failed assertion: line 173 pos 7: 'positions.isNotEmpty'"
```

Please help me make it right. Thanks

I really don't know what can I do else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this: **updated answer**

```dart
class RegistrationPagesView extends StatelessWidget {
  PageController pageController;
  RegistrationPagesView({this.pageController});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<RegistrationModel>(
        builder: (ctx, registrationModel, widget) {
      
     if (pageController.hasClients && registrationModel.currentPage != pageController.page.floor()){
        pageController.jumpToPage(registrationModel.currentPage);
      }
      return PageView(
        onPageChanged: (value) {
        registrationModel.setCurrentPage(value);
        },
        controller: pageController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        pageSnapping: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          FirstStepRegisterPage(),
          NewsPageRegistr(),
          MagazinePageRegistr(),
          RightPageRegistr(),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kouki Please tick my answer

Comment: Sorrry. unfortunatly it don't work(((( when i understand, while  class RegistrationPagesView are building  pageController has no client and i can't jump to other page in List....

Comment: @Kouki That is why i check if it hasClients

Comment: Ok. but when i understand, pageController set client in return??  becouse it never will be have client.

Comment: Are _pageController object always different. 
how to make it set the client. Otherwise, the condition will never be met.

Comment: I think i find Answer. I define pageController on Parent class. and this varible dont update now.

Comment: @Kouki ok best of luck